# uniroot() in vectorized R functions

Tags: r, function, optimization, linear-algebra

In my function below, I'm wondering why ***when I use*** a vector for argument `d`, the function works fine BUT ***when I use*** a vector for argument `t`, the function (*from `uniroot`*) throws the error **:** 
`f() values at end points not of opposite sign`

```
cii <- function(d, t = NA, n1, n2 = NA, conf.level = .95){

  ci <- Vectorize(function(d, t, n1, n2, conf.level){

    options(warn = -1)  
    alpha = (1 - conf.level)/2
    N = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1, (n1 * n2)/(n1 + n2))
    df = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1 - 1, (n1 + n2) - 2)
    d.SE = 1/sqrt(N)
    q = ifelse(is.na(t), d/d.SE, t)

    f <- function(ncp, alpha, q, df){
     alpha - suppressWarnings(pt(q, df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE))
    }

    CI <- sapply(c(alpha, 1-alpha),
      function(x) uniroot(f, interval = c(0, q+2e2), alpha = x, q = q, df = df)[[1]]*d.SE)
    CI
  })

  d <- if(missing(d)) NA else d

  data.frame(t(ci(d = d, t = t, n1 = n1, n2 = n2, conf.level = conf.level)))
}

# EXAMPLES OF USE:
cii(d = c(2, 3), n1 = 30)  # Works perfectly fine!
cii(t = c(2, 3), n1 = 30)  # Throws error: `f() values at end points not of opposite sign`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to vectorization, but the value of `q` with `t` is 2.  The endpoints (*i.e.*, 0 and 202) are both negative, so `uniroot()` assumes it doesn't cross zero.

```
> f(ncp=  0, alpha=0.025, q=2, df=29 )
[1] -0.002471819
> f(ncp=202, alpha=0.025, q=2, df=29 )
[1] -0.975
```

It does cross zero when `t` is 3.

```
> f(ncp=  0, alpha=0.025, q=3, df=29 )
[1] 0.0222504
> f(ncp=202, alpha=0.025, q=3, df=29 )
[1] -0.975
```

This graph suggests it starts just below zero, and never gets close.

```
curve(f(ncp=x, alpha=0.025, q=2, df=29 ), 0, 202)
```

[image: never-crosses-zero]

Comment: I think they're answering two different questions. [`optimize() - alpha`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optimize.html) is finding the max (which does exist), while [`uniroot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/uniroot.html) is finding the location where f=0 (which does NOT exist).  What is your goal?

Comment: This is starting to sound more like a stats/crossvalidation question than a programming/stackoverflow question.  I think the algorithm and functions are returning the correct answer.  I assume it's finding a root where ncp<0?  For your specific research question, is it ok if the solution space includes a negative noncentrality parameter?